# SimpleITK, Can't open image Viewer even if Environmental Variable si linke

Tags: python, imagej, itk, simpleitk

I want to make Slicer my default Image viewer for SimpleITK.
My Environmental Variable looks like this :

```
SITK_SHOW_COMMAND=C:\Program Files\Slicer 4.8.1\Slicer.exe
```

But i get this Error Message:

```
sitk.Show(y, "image", debugOn=True)
```

File "C:\Users\QP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\SimpleITK\SimpleITK.py", line 7745, in Show
    return _SimpleITK.Show(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK Show: C:\d\VS14-Win32-pkg\SimpleITK\Code\IO\src\sitkShow.cxx:495:
sitk::ERROR: No appropriate executable found.

I tried it with multiple other Viewers but i can`t get it to work

Comment: Please don't use images of code, put the actual code in the question using code formatting (four spaces at the start of line) :)

Comment: With the debugOn flag set to True, you should be able to see the actual command SimpleITK is trying to execute.  Can you post the entire output?  I'm guessing because you have spaces in the path name, it's not getting properly parsed.

Comment: Hi Simon, were you able to solve the problem?